# Transpose and copy column data to each row

Tags: javascript, python, excel, csv, scripting

I have data set up in the following structure

```
  A ,B ,C ,D ,E
1 a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
2 a2,b2,c2,d2,e2
3 a3,b3,c3,d3,e3
4 a4,b4,c4,d4,e4
```

And I'd like to take x fields from each row under column E such that the following affect can happen

```
  A ,B ,C ,D ,E
1 a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,e2,e3
2 a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,e3,e4
3 a3,b3,c3,d3,e3,e4,etc
4 a4,b4,c4,d4,e4,etc,etc
```

I just used etc, becaue I'd imagine the idea of what I'm trying to do would be put through.

Essentially transposing data only allows me to take a area of a column and turn it into a row, but I do not want to delete the data after transposing, I simply want to copy those area, But I have a large spread sheet(1500 rows currently and growing)

Though I'm using a spread sheet, this is simply a CSV and I'm comfortable using various scripting languages or programming languages if need be, I've considered C++,python,javascript and so on but am not sure what is the simplist way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Could you make your goal a bit more clear? I understood you're trying to get an arbitrary number of fields from one row and copy them to the last column of the same row, right?

How are you processing your CSV file, have you already started reading/parsing it in any language?

And my last question, are you trying to create a script/parse to simply transform the CSV and you're done or do you need it as some sort of module/plugin in a larger application?

Comment: Yes, I corrected my example. In my actual test. I have 1500 rows with 15 columns. I am operating on my last column. Essentially I'm starting from the very first row(i) and taking the 30(J) fields UNDER that field and I want to transpose(rotate) them so that they are in front of the end of the row

Comment: So from your example above, you're not touching columns A-D but only want to take values from the E-column and append them to the E-Column value of the current row you are operating on?

Comment: What do you want to do in your edge cases where there is no value to grab, e.g. where your 'etc' values are in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do basically what you're asking about. First some dummy data:

```
def char_range(c1, c2):
    """Generates the characters from `c1` to `c2`, inclusive."""
    for c in xrange(ord(c1), ord(c2)+1):
        yield chr(c)

matrix = [[c + str(i) for c in char_range('a', 'e')] for i in range(1, 5)]
```

That gives us:

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'], 
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2'],
 ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3'],
 ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4']]
```

Now some variables to make the expression easier to read:

```
# How many values you want to grab for each row
x = 3

# Length of the last column in the matrix
last = len(matrix)
```

Now the magics. I made the assumption that, if we've reached the end of the last row, we just put less values. That should only apply for your last `x` rows.

```
[mr + [row[-1] for row in matrix[min(i+1, last):min(i+1+grab, last)]]
 for (i, mr) in enumerate(matrix)]
```

resulting in:

```
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4'],
 ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4'],
 ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4'],
 ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'e4'],
 ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4']]
```

Notice the use of `min` here since we don't want to go outside the bounds of the matrix, and we don't know if it's a square matrix etc. Other than that, the expression says "construct a new row containing the ith row from the original matrix, and add on the last element of each of the rows from `min(i+1, last)` to `min(i+1+grab, last)` "